# How to identify hung queries, their importance, and then take action using command line?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization

From a production support perspective, how can we find hung queries and then find how important they are and then how to deal with them?

I tried only `processlist` which gives currently running queries but how to decide their importance and then act accordingly?

We don't have any MySQL performance tool with UI in existence in our environment, so how can I do this using command line?

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; would be more useful and include the Query. View profile, Network profile for contact info and on our links page we have listed JetProfiler that would be very helpful for your situation to find Top Queries (most costly) with 2 hours of info.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, PROCESSLIST output sharing is not possible for me as this is related to banking domain and I'm not allowed to paste internal data on public websites, as it will show many of the queries.

Comment: The best we can do in this case is suggest tools for you to use or tutorials.  I have suggested JetProfiler for your consideration.  This URL should be useful to you, especially since you can not share any data.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-processlist/  If you are not using MariaDB, minor adjustments may be required. The BEST to you and your associates.  We will help in any way we can.

Answer (score 1):

There are two utilities that you may want to look at:

1) mytop

2) innotop

They are, as their names imply, the MySQL equivalent of the "top" system utility.

They won't help you figure out how "important" a query is because this requires deep knowledge of the system issuing the queries.

For a deeper, longer term (rather than real-time, catch-it-while-it's-running) insight, you can capture the slow log (adjust long_query_time appropriately to your opinion on what is problematic), and analyze the slow log using one of the following two tools:

1) mysqldumpslow

2) pt-query-digest

These will give you insight into which query "templates" are the ones consuming the largest amount of the server's CPU time.

When you outgrow the capabilities of the command line tools and you find you need a deeper long-term insight, I suggest you look at PMM (Percona Monitoring and Management), it is an extremely useful took for identifying performance issues on database (and not just database) servers.

Comment: What to do about taking action on those hung queries,I mean how actually we can reduce load on MySQL server.

Comment: Once you identified the slow/problematic/impactful queries, you need to optimize them. Some can be improved using more appropriate indexing. Some may need to be re-written in a better way. Some may need materialized views to be made efficient. Query optimization is a complex task. If you don't have a skilled database specialist in-house, there are plenty of database consultancies around that you can engage to do this sort of thing for you, or you can try posting a job for it on Upwork. Expect it to cost somewhere in the 4-figure $, depending on the number of problematic queries you have.

Comment: @PrakashG - For "load on the server", `pt-query-digest` defaults to listing "worst first".  For `mysqldumpslow`, use `-s t`.